# How do I get a list of all the people whose answer I accepted?

Tags: discussion, search

A while back I saw something like a SQL query engine for various post related searches but I can't find any FAQ/reference on how to use it. If you could point me to such a page/post I will try to answer this question on my own.

Anyway, I'd like to see a list of the users whose answers I accepted because I they were the most complete and useful. Specifically I'm curious to see if I accepted the same person more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Using it is dead simple; you just [compose an SQL query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and run it (you'll notice the database layout on the right-hand side; see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678) for some more detailed information). There are a couple special features, such as parameters and "magic" column names on which the [documentation](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) leaves something to be desired, though.

Here's a query I just wrote that [lists the users you've accepted the most answers from](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67973/people-who-ive-accepted-the-most-answers-from).

Comment: It's not simple for me :( Thank you for helping. I'm not able to get results from your query. I'm only trying my Stack Overflow id, 1238040, which is what makes sense.

Comment: @HeitorChang The Explorer doesn't query the live database; the current data dump is from March 15th. It seems all your questions were asked after that, so regrettably it won't work for you until the next dump.

Comment: That explains it. Looking back I should have also tried the query with other UserIds. Thanks again!

Comment: @lunboks considering you were the last editor of the answer I'm surprised you didn't mention [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/148672)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Right, thanks. That was on account of me forgetting that it even existed.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) would be the tool you speak of.

I don't believe there is a query like the one you describe, but you can write one.